# Is it possible to print to a Samsung ML-1865 printer?

Tags: printing

I have read, that Samsung provides just binary drivers for Intel.

What I have done so far: I have installed CUPS and added a ML-1760 printer, because a ML-1865 driver was not available. After that I printed a test page. The printer generates some noise and does not print anything. And CUPS does not report any error message. The test page print job just disappears.

Comment: Googling for 'samsung ml-1865 raspberry pi' and it would suggest it may be possible... What have you done so far to get it working?

Comment: @Dirk I do not want to pass the printer as a RAW device to a Windows or MacOS client. I want to print from Rasbian.

Comment: this is more a linux question ... google `samsung ml-1865 debian`

Comment: @jsotola It is a ARM problem.